# Pyspark: Average of timestamp

Tags: python, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have a data frame who looks like:-

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|      user_name     |       working_hour|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|         ABC        |2019-10-21 09:00:02|
|         XYZ        |2019-10-21 09:15:01|
|         DEF        |2019-10-21 08:55:00|
|         ABC        |2019-10-22 09:40:00|
|         XYZ        |2019-10-22 07:05:01|
|         DEF        |2019-10-22 08:45:00|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I want the average working hour for each user. I have working hours on different dates. I am trying with groupBy users. It's given like this.

```
df_avg = df_work_hours.groupBy('user_name').agg(sql_functions.avg('working_hour').alias('avg_hour'))

+--------------------+--------------------+
|      user_name     |            avg_hour|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|         ABC        |      1.5717579755E9|
|         XYZ        |1.5717276003333333E9|
|         DEF        |          1.571658E9|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

But I want to like this:-

```
+--------------------+------------------+
|      user_name     | avg(working_hour)|
+--------------------+------------------+
|         ABC        |          09:20:01|
|         XYZ        |          08:10:01|
|         DEF        |          08:50:00|
+--------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Should we assume that each user can have working hours over more than 2 dates? And what is ur spark version ?

Comment: yes, my spark version 2.4.5.@MohammadMurtazaHashmi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, just convert the working_hour to unix_timestamp and then take the average:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn('working_hour', expr('unix_timestamp(concat("2019-01-01", right(working_hour,9)))')) \
  .groupby('user_name') \
  .agg(expr("from_unixtime(avg(working_hour),'HH:mm:ss') as avg_hour")) \
  .show()
+---------+--------+                                                            
|user_name|avg_hour|
+---------+--------+
|      DEF|08:50:00|
|      XYZ|08:10:01|
|      ABC|09:20:01|
+---------+--------+
```

Or use DSL functions:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('working_hour', F.unix_timestamp(F.date_format('working_hour', '2019-01-01 HH:mm:ss'))) \
   .groupby('user_name') \
   .agg(F.from_unixtime(F.avg('working_hour'),'HH:mm:ss').alias('avg_hour')) \
   .show()
```

**Some explanation:**

(1) we use [expr](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime) function to wrap up an SQL expression and return the result into a column. this is a convenient way to access SparkSQL's builtin functions, see [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html).

(2) use `concat("2019-01-01", right(working_hour,9))` to convert all the *working_hour* into the same date so that date difference won't influence the calculation of average. (here we concatenate the string "2019-01-01" with the last 9 characters of *working_hour*). (notice that the SparkSQL [right](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#right) function will cast the first argument into string internally).
see also [date_format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format) function to handle the same.

(3) then use [unix_timestamp](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime) to convert the above result into unix timestamp (bigint)

(4) groupby(user_name) and take the `avg` of the result from (3), and then convert it back to the time format using [from_unixtime](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime).

Comment: Can you explain what you done here? Means what are expr functions and concat functions doing here?

Comment: @jxc nice catch on the date difference. thumbs up

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and answer. @jxc

Comment: @jxc - nice solution, mine is little harsh on timezone :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried approaching this as below-

1. ### Read the input

```scala
 val spark = sqlContext.sparkSession
    val implicits = spark.implicits
    import implicits._
    val schema = StructType(
      Array(StructField("user_name", DataTypes.StringType),
        StructField("working_hour", DataTypes.TimestampType))
      )
    val data1 =
      """
        |  ABC        |2019-10-21 09:00:02
        |  XYZ        |2019-10-21 09:15:01
        |  DEF        |2019-10-21 08:55:00
        |  ABC        |2019-10-22 09:40:00
        |  XYZ        |2019-10-22 07:05:01
        |  DEF        |2019-10-22 08:45:00
      """.stripMargin

    val df1 = spark.read
      .schema(schema)
      .option("sep", "|")
      .csv(data1.split(System.lineSeparator()).map(_.replaceAll("""^\s*|\s$""", "")).toSeq.toDS())
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()
```

Result-

```
+-----------+-------------------+
|user_name  |working_hour       |
+-----------+-------------------+
|ABC        |2019-10-21 09:00:02|
|XYZ        |2019-10-21 09:15:01|
|DEF        |2019-10-21 08:55:00|
|ABC        |2019-10-22 09:40:00|
|XYZ        |2019-10-22 07:05:01|
|DEF        |2019-10-22 08:45:00|
+-----------+-------------------+

root
 |-- user_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- working_hour: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

2. ### Find the average in seconds and convert it to HH:MM:SS

```scala
val processedDf = df1.
      withColumn("diff", unix_timestamp(col("working_hour")) - unix_timestamp(to_date(col("working_hour"))))
      .groupBy("user_name")
      .agg(avg("diff").cast(LongType).as("avg"))


   val HHMMSS =  udf((seconds: Long) => {
      val df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
      df.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))
      df.format(seconds * 1000)
    })
    processedDf.withColumn("hhmmss", HHMMSS(col("avg")))
      .show(false)
```

Result-

```
+-----------+-----+--------+
|user_name  |avg  |hhmmss    |
+-----------+-----+--------+
|ABC        |33601|09:20:01|
|DEF        |31800|08:50:00|
|XYZ        |29401|08:10:01|
+-----------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: This is scala code. How to write in python?@Someshwar Kale